# Blend two objects with different colors and shapes in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, blending

I have two objects with some gradients on them. Now I need to do blend them together. I did 'Object to path' on both of them and tried to do 'Generate from path/Interpolate'.

What I wish to get is point 5. from [here](https://vectortwist.com/illustrator-blend-tool-tips/) or what has been done [here](https://youtu.be/nLfjoR0YaKk?t=84).
The Interpolate action that I tried does only shape transition from object 1 to object 2. But color stays the same for all the transition steps until the object 2 which has different gradient scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do 'Path/Stroke to path' on both objects. Then check 'Interpolate style' checkbox of Interpolation.